# set different span for a every row with GridLayoutManager

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I want to set different span for every Row with `GridLayoutManager`.

```
 GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 3);
        gridView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
        gridLayoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
            @Override
            public int getSpanSize(int position) {

                Log.e("SPAN",position%3+" <=="+position);
                switch (position % 3) {
                    case 1:
                        return 1;

                    case 2:
                        return 2;

                    case 0:
                        return 3;

                    default:return 3;
                }
            }
        });
```

Above code sets as below(here imageview considered as an item)

- first row with single ImageView
- second row with three ImageView
- third row with two ImageView.

Comment: Use [StaggeredGridLayoutmanager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/StaggeredGridLayoutManager.html)

Comment: but  have achieved my requirement 70%  only third row needs to be spanned in 3 counts ..that's i want..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be issue with your logic. Try with below logic:

```
    gridLayoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GgridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
        @Override
        public int getSpanSize(int position) {

            Log.e("SPAN",position%3+" <=="+position);
            switch (position % 6) {
                case 0:
                    return 3;
                    break;
                case 1:
                case 2:
                case 3:
                case 4:
                    return 1;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    return 2;
                    break;
                default:return 3;
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int previousValue = 0;    
SpanSizeLookup spanSizeLookup = new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
                override int  getSpanSize(position){
                    if (position == 0) {
                        previousValue = 6;
                        return previousValue ;
                    }else
                    if (previousValue == 6) {
                        previousValue =3;
                        return previousValue ;
                    } else if(previousValue == 3){
                       previousValue =2;
                       return previousValue ;
                }else if(previousValue ==2){
                      previousValue  = 6;
                      return previousValue ;
                     }
            }
            GridLayoutManager glm = new GridLayoutManager(this, 6)

            glm.spanSizeLookup = spanSizeLookup;
            recycler_view.setLayoutManager(glm)
```

Comment: you can use switch inside getSpanSize() method

Comment: 1. first row with 2 imageviews.
2. secon row with 1 imageview.
3. thirs row with 3 imageviews. and rest of view too with 3 imageview  according to your condition

Comment: @unknown Try it now.

Comment: fisrt row with two imageviews and rest of all are with single imageview with updated condition

Comment: actually it divide the total numbers of column by the number returned by getspancount method

Comment: no, now first row  with 1 imageview and 2 is with 2 imageview and 3 is with 3 imageview   theses are correct but again  rest of rows are with three imageviews

Comment: goood this is according to your question.what you want after 3rd row

Comment: i mean to say is .....  again it should be span according to above three column......(if i have 9 items in a list then 3,3,3 should be span according to condition  got it? )

Comment: if you have 100 rows then first has1 img, 2 has 2 and 3 has 3 imageviews then 4 have again 1 imageviews and so on ....am i right?

Comment: if you have 100 rows then first has1 img, 2 has 2 and 3 has 3 imageviews and this cycle  should be countinued till last (100 number of item).

Comment: check it now please

Comment: no ,buddy didn't work...   only first row with single imageview and for rest data even didn't get set...  but   Second ans of my quest worked for me.. see